# how to create surface mesh from geometry Point Z with trimesh

Tags: geospatial, mesh

I want to create surface mesh from geometry point with X,Y,Z coordinates
This is how it looks now
[image]

and this is what I am trying to achieve
[image]

My code looks like this

```
agg_piezometer_readings = agg_piezometer_readings.dataframe()

filename = 'water_surface.ply'
window_spec = Window.partitionBy("m_hole_id").orderBy(F.col("surface_head").desc())

ranked_df = agg_piezometer_readings.withColumn("highest_elevation", F.row_number().over(window_spec))
agg_piezometer_readings = ranked_df.filter(F.col("highest_elevation") == 1)

agg_piezometer_readings = agg_piezometer_readings.orderBy(F.col("m_z").asc())
points_array = np.array(agg_piezometer_readings.select("m_x", "m_y", "m_z").collect()) 

# Delaunay method
tri = Delaunay(points_array)
vertices = tri.points
faces = tri.simplices

mesh = trimesh.Trimesh(vertices=vertices, faces=faces, process=True)
```

I want to correctly order and mesh points from left to right